# Constraint Layout programmatically MATCH_CONSTRAINT width not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I'm generating my `(constraint)`layout programmatically.
Everything shows up as it's supposed to, with proper constraints, but I can't make my views `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` width to spread as it's supposed to (like when you set 0dp when making it with XML).
I found this:
[Set ConstraintLayout width to match parent width programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249150/set-constraintlayout-width-to-match-parent-width-programmatically)
helpful, but doesn't work at all.

Posting my layout generaitng function below:

```
private fun generateLayout(formData: Form) {
        val decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(formData.form)
        val decodedString = String(decodedBytes)
        val gson = Gson()
        val formFields = gson.fromJson(decodedString, Array<FormField>::class.java).asList()

        val constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout)
        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        val layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, WRAP_CONTENT)
        var views: ArrayList<View> = ArrayList()
        var formFieldsCounter: Int = 0

        //parsing fields form model class to actual view
        formFields.forEach {
            var view: View? = null
            view?.layoutParams = layoutParams
            when (it.type) {
                "textField" -> {
                    view = EditText(this)
                    view.hint = it.fieldName
                }
                "checkBox" -> {
                    view = CheckBox(this)
                    //view.isChecked = it.isChecked
                }
            }
            view!!.id = it.id!!
            view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            views.add(view)
            constraintLayout.addView(view)
        }

        //set constraints between created views
        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
        views.forEach {
            constraintSet.constrainDefaultWidth(it.id, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_SPREAD)
            //TOP CONSTRAINT
            if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintTop_toSBottmOf == 0)
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP,
                    R.id.applicationNumberTextView,
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
                )
            else if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintTop_toSBottmOf != null)
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP,
                    formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintTop_toSBottmOf!!,
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
                )
            //BOTTOM CONSTRAINT
            if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf == 0)
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                    R.id.parent,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP
                )
            else if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf != null)
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                    formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf!!,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP
                )
            //LEFT CONSTRAINT
            if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintStart_toSEndOf == 0)
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                    R.id.parent,
                    ConstraintSet.LEFT
                )
            else if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintStart_toSEndOf != null)
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                    formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintStart_toSEndOf!!,
                    ConstraintSet.RIGHT
                )
            //RIGHT CONSTRAINT
            if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf == 0)
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                    R.id.parent,
                    ConstraintSet.RIGHT
                )
            else if (formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf != null)
                constraintSet.connect(
                    it.id,
                    ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                    formFields[formFieldsCounter].layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf!!,
                    ConstraintSet.LEFT
                )
            formFieldsCounter++
        }
        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
    }
```

This is what i get:

[image]

It's pretty much the same what I get without setting

```
view?.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

or

```
constraintSet.constrainDefaultWidth(it.id, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_SPREAD)
```

I'm stuck with it for a while now. Thanks a million for any help :)

Comment: Each view needs its own layout params and you create one that is shared by all the views, so move the creation of _LayoutParams_ inside the loop. There may be something else that is not right, but that will be a start.

Comment: @Cheticamp in forEach loop I'm creating new View, than assigns some inherited View like EditText to it and add the View to to constraintLayout, then loop starts again, creating empty View assigning some View to it etc and i set my layoutParams to empty view: View that is created every time loop rounds. Am i right or im missing something? Im more used to Java, where it would be new View view;  view=EditText which should work just right. I guess that what im doing is kotlin equivalent

Comment: What I am saying is that you need a distinct layout params for each view. Views cannot share a layout params within _ConstraintLayout_. Make a new _LayoutParams_ each time you make a new view and assign the new layout params to the new view. As it stands, all your views use the same layout params. That is a problem. Make that change to see what happens.

Comment: Ok, i see.  That's 1 step forward, but it's ain't working yet. I'm gonna find out what's the problem here, problably make some refactor, becouse its messy atm. Thanks