# Is it a Correct Way to set Height of Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-constraintlayout

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int screenHeight = size.y;

        // get layout parameters for that view
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) askedQuestionCl.getLayoutParams();

        // change height of the params e.g. 480dp
        layoutParams.height = screenHeight;

        // initialize new parameters for my element
        askedQuestionCl.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Is this a correct way to update the Layout Height equal to the screen Height of mobile programmatically?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249150/set-constraintlayout-width-to-match-parent-width-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for Your Response. Your provided thread has helped me to rectify my coding. Thanks again. @Manohar

Answer (score 0):

```
  ConstraintLayout constrainLayout  = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.clyt);
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lparam = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) constrainLayout.getLayoutParams();
    lparam .matchConstraintPercentHeight = (float) floatvalue add E.X0.4;
    constrainLayout.setLayoutParams(lparam);
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.